# Can you explain why the first unwrapped method reference does not compile?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

In this example, passing a method reference to `Stream.of` does not work but once it's wrapped it works. I can't quite get my head around why this is. Isn't the method reference equivalent to the functional interface?

```
public class A {

    String a() {
        return "";
    }

    void b() {
        Stream.of(this::a); // won't compile
        Stream.of(wrap(this::a)); // will compile
    }

    static <T> Supplier<T> wrap(Supplier<T> f) {
        return f;
    }
}
```

Comment: `this::a` is not a `Supplier<A>` but (due to it being a variable reference) a `Function<A, String>` or `Supplier<String>`

Comment: Are you confusing this with `Stream.generate(this::a)`?

Comment: You've convoluted your problem by calling your generic parameter the same name as the class.

Comment: @AndyCribbens you don't need any casts, added my answer

Answer (score 1):

`Stream.of(T)` expects an `Object` and you pass to it a method reference in the first statement. But an `Object` parameter is not a functional interface,  so it cannot accept a method reference or a lambda that is not specifically typed.
With lambda, it would produce also an error : `Stream.of(()->this.a())`.
A simpler example could be  `Stream.of(()-> "foo")` that will just not compile.

But if you type the method reference or the lambda it works :

```
Stream.of((Supplier<String>) this::a)
```

or

```
Stream.of((Supplier<String>) () -> this.a())
```

In the working statement you pass to `Stream.of(T)` a parameter that is a `Supplier<String>`. That refers to a functional interface but that is typed as in the previous working examples, so it is valid as parameter that expects an `Object`.

Comment: `an object parameter cannot accept a method reference` This seems wrong upon reading it, could you clarify/reword? I can absolutely pass a method reference (a value which is a subclass of object) to an object parameter, generic or not

Comment: @Rogue  "I can absolutely pass a method reference (a value which is a subclass of object) to an object parameter, generic or not"  ? A method reference expression is not a subclass of Object. So no you should not be able.  Can you illustrate with an example ?

Comment: swap PSV with "public static void": `PSV example(Object o) {} PSV run() {} .......  example((Runnable) MyClass::run);` you need to specify the functional interface type, since otherwise you refer to the most generic type (Object). There's no concrete type for functional interfaces, if you generically bounded to FunctionalInterface in fact you get a great error: "FunctionalInterface is not a functional interface". You can add to this example (e.g. make #run print, and try to run the object in #example) if you want to prove it further

Comment: @Rogue I see what you mean and I agree that it may be ambiguous.  But I note in your example you are constraint to cast to a FI class to make the method reference/lambda compile. So you just proved that  you  cannot absolutely pass a method reference to an object parameter. You have to first cast it to an Object and more particularly a Functional interface object. That is which I explained in the second point.

Comment: You can assign it to a variable and pass it that way without a cast. It's due to signature ambiguity, not inability to pass as an Object. Same as if you had two methods with the same name accepting two different object parameters, and you passed `null` (casting the null required). I believe per the JSR it was made a compile time error to pass a lambda/MR for a non-FI parameter (e.g. Object), but that doesn't preclude them from being objects themselves. I'm fairly sure you can do a cast of object there as well if you wish, but not in front of a computer to double check

Comment: @Rogue Concerning ambiguity I am not sure since `Stream.of(T t)` where T has Object as erasure should not be ambiguous.  I reworded to take into consideration the type part. Do you think it more accurate ?

Answer (score 1):

`Stream.of` has the following signature:

```
public static<T> Stream<T> of(T t)
```

The following example will compile because you explicitly providing a type information for `T`.

```
Stream<Supplier<String>> a = Stream.of(this::a);
```

The first example `Stream.of(this::a);` equivalent to:

```
Object a = this::a;
```

where `Object` is not a functional interface and will not compile.

Providing with a functional interface this example compiles:

```
Runnable a = this::a;
Stream.of(a);
```

In the second example, `wrap` provides a functional interface `Supplier`

Answer (score 1):

`this::a` is contextless and could mean different things. You need to provide some context to help the compiler to figure out what you actually meant by `this::a`.

```
Stream.<Supplier<String>>of(this::a);
```

Though, that `Stream<Supplier<String>>` doesn't seem to be what you wanted. If you need a `Stream<String>`, use `Stream.generate`: no extra type information needed since the method takes a `Supplier<T>` (no ambiguity here).

```
Stream.generate(this::a);
```

On a side note, both statements expect you to save their results into variables. Defining variables of the right type often facilitates resolving such issues.

```
Stream<Supplier<String>> s1 = Stream.of(this::a);
Stream<String> s2 = Stream.generate(this::a);
```

All credit to @J-Alex and @Holger for their precious comments.